# Bash Script for deleting old backup files

Tags: bash, backup

every night my server creates backups for every mysql database. All of these files are saved in a folder like /backup/mysql/2014-11-28. Over the last few months a lot of folders and files have been stored in that directory and I would like to reduce this.

Therefore I would need a bash script which deletes every folder in the given directory, except every folder created this month (not in the last 30 days, but the actual month) and except one backup from every week (for example the backup from sunday). Since I have no clue how to do the sunday party I decided it would be simpler to keep the backups from the 07th, the 14th, the 21st and the the 28th.

```
#!/bin/bash
in_array() {
local haystack=${1}[@]
local needle=${2}
for i in ${!haystack}; do
    if [[ ${i} == ${needle} ]]; then
        return 0
    fi
done
return 1
}

YEAR=`date +%Y`
LASTYEAR=`date +%Y -d "1 year ago"`
MONTH=`date +%m`
DAYS="07 14 21 28"
for i in $( ls ); do
BACKUP_YEAR=$(echo "${i}" | cut -d'-' -f1)
BACKUP_MONTH=$(echo "${i}" | cut -d'-' -f2)
BACKUP_DAY=$(echo "${i}" | cut -d'-' -f3)

DELETE=false

if [[ "$BACKUP_YEAR" == "$YEAR" ]]; then
    if [[ "$BACKUP_MONTH" != "$MONTH" ]]; then
            if [ $(in_array $DAYS "$BACKUP_DAY") ]; then
                DELETE=true
            fi
    fi
fi
if [[ "$BACKUP_YEAR" == "$LASTYEAR" ]]; then
    if [[ "$BACKUP_DAY" != ${DAYS[0]} ]]; then
        DELETE=true
    fi
fi
if [ "$DELETE" = true ] ; then
    #OUTPUT=`rm -v -R $i`
    echo $i
fi
done
```

The second part (backups from the year before) works perfectly fine, but the first part (for backups from this year) doesn't work and I don't know why. I found the function on this site, but I guess somehow my call is wrong.

EDIT: The code I am now using:

```
#!/bin/bash
read YEAR MONTH <<<$(date "+%Y %m")
LASTYEAR=$(( YEAR-1 ))
DAYS=" 07 14 21 28 "

for fn in $( ls )
do
    if   ([ "${fn:0:4}" = "$YEAR" ] &&
    [ "${fn:5:2}" != "$MONTH" ] &&
    [ "${DAYS/ ${fn:8:2} /}" = "$DAYS" ]) || ([ "${fn:0:4}" = "$LASTYEAR" ] &&
    [ "${fn:8:2}" != ${DAYS:1:2} ])
    then
         #OUTPUT=`rm -v -R $fn`
         echo "$fn"
   fi
done
```

Comment: Hi David. Please, answer yourself the following question: what is the main difference between the "second part" and the "first part"? -- The use of the `in_array` function.

Comment: `in_array 07 14 21 28 19` may be an example of the arguments passed to the `in_array` function. Are they right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
read YEAR MONTH <<<$(date "+%Y %m")
LASTYEAR=$(( YEAR-1 ))
DAYS=" 07 14 21 28 "

for fn in $( ls )
do
     DELETE=false

     if   [ "${fn:0:7}" = "$YEAR-$MONTH" ] &&
          [ "${DAYS/ ${fn:8:2} /}" != "$DAYS" ]
     then
          DELETE=true
     elif [ "${fn:0:4}" = "$LASTYEAR" ] &&
          [ "${fn:8:2}" != ${DAYS:1:2} ]
     then
          DELETE=true
     fi

     if [ "$DELETE" = true ]
     then
          #OUTPUT=`rm -v -R $fn`
          echo "$fn"
     fi
done
```

Assuming that a file name matches the following date format `YYYY-MM-DD`, for instance, `2014-03-27`, the expression `${fn:0:7}` would be `2014-03`; `${fn:8:2}` would be `27`; `${fn:0:4}` would be `2014`.

Read the bash manual pages about the [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

The expression `${DAYS/ ${fn:8:2} /}` checks the day from the filename (wrapped by white spaces) is found in the `DAYS` list. It would be equivalent to `echo "${DAYS}" | grep -q "${BACKUP_DAY}"`.

note: it is possible to reduce the commands inside the `for` loop (join `if` and `elif` by means of a `||` and remove the `DELETE` variable checking and the `DELETE` variable itself) but I decided to keep the look of the original script.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. that worked perfectly. I actually shortened it according to your suggestion. I edited my original post to show the code I am now using